# How to access .nsf file by java for desktop application without IBM lotus installed

Tags: java, lotus-notes

I don't have IBM lotus installed, but I want to access some database containing .nsf file through java for a desktop application.

Comment: i am using local database.it need to have any server if i have NOtes.jar

Answer (score 0):

your .nsf database is on lotus server or local?
if server, you can use DIIOP access it.
if local, must install lotus domino/notes.
what ever you need Notes.jar(local access) or NCSO.jar(remote access).

Comment: i have database at local i want to access it local i have notes.jar but on creating session by Session s = NotesFactory.createSession(); returning s=null.whether it require any server to run.